# r: Is my way of projecting longitude and latitude coordinates into a shapefile on a map correct?

Tags: r, shapefile, r-sf

I have a dataframe of polygons listed with the longitude and latitude coordinates of each vertex.  Consider the following dataframe:

```
shape    longitude latitude
polygon1 -0.15     51
polygon1 -0.148    51.3
polygon1 -0.148    51.3
polygon1 -0.15     51
polygon2 -0.15     51.5
polygon2 -0.148    51.5
polygon2 -0.148    52
polygon2 -0.15     52
```

I want to use the sf library and I convert the coordinates into shapefile polygons. First I set the coordinate reference system to 4326 which comprises a standard coordinate frame for the Earth.  Then I transform the coordinate reference system to 27700 which is the British national grid(my points are in the UK). Here is the code I use:

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
data <- data %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c('longitude', 'latitude')) %>%
  st_set_crs(4326)
data = data %>% st_transform(27700)
data <- data %>%
  group_by(shape) %>%
  summarise(do_union=FALSE) %>%
  st_cast("POLYGON")
```

After projecting the shapefile, I calculate the distance between the polgons as 22247.47 metres using st_distance.  Using the haversine formula, I get 22238.99 metres.  Is it normal for there to be some variation?

It is important that I am correctly mapping my longitude and latitude coordinates onto the UK in order to get the correct distances.  Is my method correct?

Comment: looks fine... why are your doubting your results?  Check results visually: `mapview::mapview(data)`

Comment: When I calculate the haversine distance I get 22238.99 metres.  But I suppose it's normal for there to be some difference between the two?

Comment: You can make your polygon slightly easier / faster with `sfheaders::sf_polygon( obj = data, x = "longitude", y = "latitude", polygon_id = "shape")`